# Is it Possible to Select Specfiic Fields from a Randomly Retrieved BsonDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I'm using the following code to retrieve a random document from a MongoDB database (client, database and collection parameters have been intentionally changed).

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<BsonDocument> Get()
{
    var client = new MongoClient(CLIENT);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(COLLECTION);


    var document = collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).First();

    Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    return document;
}
```

> [{"name":"_id","value":"5c4f2f7b9914ed3a4b8a9b8f"},{"name":"id","value":3470264},{"name":"coord","value":[{"name":"lon","value":-48.479172},{"name":"lat","value":-20.94944}]},{"name":"country","value":"BR"},{"name":"geoname","value":[{"name":"cl","value":"P"},{"name":"code","value":"PPL"},{"name":"parent","value":3448433}]},{"name":"langs","value":[[{"name":"link","value":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bebedouro"}]]},{"name":"name","value":"Bebedouro"},{"name":"stat","value":[{"name":"level","value":1.0},{"name":"population","value":71862}]},{"name":"stations","value":[[{"name":"id","value":4566},{"name":"dist","value":76},{"name":"kf","value":1}]]},{"name":"zoom","value":9}]

However, since some records contain more fields than others, I'd like to select a specific two for further processing. Using the result above, these would be:

> {"name":"country","value":"BR"} {"name":"name","value":"Bebedouro"}

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Clarification:   you say the DB info was changed.   But the structure is the same, yes?   Your example above suggests that a normal document with key/value pairs was turned into an array of keyname / value tuples.   Could you do a findOne() on your collection and post that as an example of a doc from which you would like to extract 2 fields?

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, by that I meant that the client, database and collection parameters were changed for the purpose of this post. Meanwhile, I'm trying to use the FindOne() function and am being prompted with an error that "'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'FindOne' and no accessible extension method 'FindOne' accepting a first argument of type 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>' could be found". Also, the result posted earlier is in raw data format.

Comment: From the mongo shell, do this:

     db.nameOfYourCollection.findOne();

Edit the things you don't want us to see and post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I've found a solution to the problem.

1) The method's result was changed to tuple.
2) The values of the two fields, that is city and country were retrieved and converted to string.
3) The two values were added to a tuple.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<Tuple<string, string>> Get()
{
    var client = new MongoClient(CLIENT);
    var database = client.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
    var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(COLLECTION);

    var document = collection.AsQueryable().Sample(1).First();

    var city = document.GetValue("name").ToString();
    var country = document.GetValue("country").ToString();

    Tuple<string, string> result = new Tuple<string, string>(city, country);

    Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    return result;
}
```

And the result is now the following.

> {"item1":"Lakewood","item2":"US"}